# Access Django models from forms.py

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have a student model and I want to display all the students in a selector element on my forms.py.

```
from django import forms
from student.views import *

class selector(forms.Form):

    Selector_student = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
        required=True,
        widget=forms.Select({'class': 'form-control'}),
        choices= student_name_list
    )
```

To get the student_name_list I acces to the database in views.py :

```
def student_view(request):
     current_user_id = request.user.id
     student_name = Student.objects.filter(user_id = current_user_id).values('name');

         if request.method == 'POST':
             form = Selector(request.POST)
             if form.is_valid():
                Student_name = form.get('Student_name')
             return redirect(reverse('success'))

         else:
              form = Selector()
         return render(request, 'heroconfigurer/heroconfigurer.html',
              {'student_name_list': student_name, 'form': form})
```

My template.html is:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/main.css' %}">

<div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="page-header"><h2>Hero Configurer</h2></div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-offset-3">
            <form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                {% csrf_token %}  
                {{ form.as_p }}
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How does your view relate to your form?

Comment: My view will get the student name using POST method

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're doing with the `student_name` variable you've declared in the view, but you would need to do the same query in the form if you intend to show the same choices, or you need to pass some additional information to your form.

I would do:

```
from django import forms

class SelectorForm(forms.Form):

    def __init__(*self, *args, **kwargs):
        student_choices = kwargs.pop('student_choices')
        super(SelectorForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields['student'] = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
            widget=forms.Select({'class': 'form-control'}),
            choices=student_choices
        )
```

this way you can get the `student_choices` once in the view, and just pass them to the form:

```
def student_view(request):
    students = Student.objects.filter(user_id=request.user.id).values_list(
        'name', flat=True)
    student_form = StudentForm(request.POST or None, student_choices=students)

    if request.method == 'POST' and student_form.is_valid():
        student_name = student_form.cleaned_data.get('student')
        redirect(reverse('success'))

    return render(request, 'your-template.html',
        {'students': students, 'student_form': student_form})
```

On a small side note, you really need to be using proper casing on your Python classes, which should **always** be title cased. Otherwise, you'll have a hard time distinguishing between instances and definitions or the class not to mention function names, variables, etc.

Comment: Small question... doesn't the call to super create the field in the first place to which this would recreate it? (or have you just moved this definition inside the init)

Comment: Not if it's not already defined. That's why I just moved the field definition inside the `__init__` after the call to `super`. That's really the only difference in our answers :)

Comment: @Brandon - Sure, thats what I thought :)

Comment: `form` was undefined in my code. Sorry about that; coffee is still kicking in. I've updated the sample. I'm not sure how any of the code from the answers posted here would result in an unpacking error.

Comment: Also note that a `MultipleChoiceField` expects a list, not a list of tuples as returned by `.values()` note that my example uses the flattened form `.values_list('name', flat=True)` which returns a list of values.

Comment: I'm deleting my answer.. I'm pretty sure it can be solved by using the exact code shown in this answer, although there isn't really a need to use `values` or `values_list`

Comment: Brandom, I am sorry your answer is working now! But what about if I change the student name by student id ? I get this error 'int' object is not iterable

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: I mean: values_list(
        'id', flat=True)

Comment: That shouldn't cause a problem for the MultipleChoiceField. Are you needing to display the Student name in the select, but have the value of the field be the Student.id?

Comment: I need to display the student id

Comment: Changing the field you're using shouldn't matter. `Student.objects.filter(user_id=request.user.id).values_list('id', flat=True)` should still return a list, even if there's only 1 value. Of course, you'll need to update the rest of the view code accordingly.

Comment: I update my question, shall I modify my template.html?

Comment: It doesn't matter when you're just outputting the form using `as_p ()`. The form should render correctly given the data is correct. If it's not, something else is wrong with your code.

Comment: I think that the I have an error because my forms have other code like: NumberOfCalls = forms.CharField()

Comment: That sounds like a different question :)